# How do I change the time format used by ls command line on osx?

Tags: command-line, unix

I want to make `ls` display time in `ISO` format (military format). How can I change this behavior?

On Linux I knew that I could force ls to display time in long format by usin `--full-time` but this doesn't work on OS X.

Update: I know that the format used by the command is based on the `locale` settings. The problem is that on OS X I was not able to use the trick of setting `LC_TIME=en_DK`.

Comment: A non-answer, but still possibly useful: The stat(1) command is quite flexible and can be made to display time stamps in any desired format.

Comment: gls (gnu ls) I mentioned in my answer can take a --style= flag where you can specify a +FORMAT string, so you can make the date appear whatever way you wish.

Comment: I wish I knew a way. Apple's BSD manual for `ls` seems to offer nothing for formatting datetimes, other than changing timezone and sorting by datetime rather than alpha. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html

Answer (score 20):

If you install gnu coreutils then gnu ls is available, which will do as required. If you use brew as a package manager, it's as simple as:

```
brew install coreutils
gls -l --time-style=full-iso
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful but does not solve the problem. The full format used is still not ISO-8601.

Comment: OK - you can install gnu coreutils which includes gnu ls, which will do what you want. Easiest way is one of brew, MacPorts or Fink. I use brew - so just running 'brew install coreutils' works. You'll then have gls available.

Comment: Notably, `brew install coreutils` results in `/usr/local/bin/gls` being installed, so you need to run `gls` instead of `ls`.

Comment: You need to specify the time format with `gls -l --time-syle="+%I"` (or whatever the correct `gdate`-style format is for ISO-8601).

Comment: Correct call is thus; gls -l --time-style=full-iso

Answer (score 19):

OS X's built-in `ls` command does not take time formatting arguments, but the `stat` command takes strftime format strings so you can get an approximation of what you want by doing:

```
stat -l -t '%FT%T' *
```

The `%FT%T` produces an ISO8601 local timestamp. Add a `%z` if you want a UTC offset.

But while the timestamp is right, the rest only approximates what you'd get from ls. For instance, `ls -l` properly aligns fields into columns, can colorize output, and of course it lists directory contents rather than requiring you to pass all filenames as arguments. You can at least reproduce the proper alignment by piping the output through `tr` to convert all spaces into tabs:

```
stat -l -t '%F%T' * | tr ' ' \\t
```

Alternatively, I think it should be possible to get `ls -l` to produce an ISO8601 timestamp by defining a custom locale, but I have not seen it done.

Answer (score 2):

Using **macOS Monterey 12** the following works for me:

```sh
ls -lD '%FT%T'
```

I'm using an alias that also preserves colored output:

```sh
alias ls="ls -D '%FT%T' --color=auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stat -l -t '%FT%T' *
```

That worked fine for me. I needed to see both file size and time stamp. Wonder why Apple saw fit to discard the pretty-much-standard time mod o/p from `ls -l`. I even hauled out my *UNIX in a Nutshell*!

Answer (score -2):

`ls -l --time-style=iso` works fine for me.

Comment: Doesn't. Mountain Lion.

Comment: Not on Mavericks either.

Comment: It probably works fine for the OP, because he or she has installed a non-system `ls` without realizing it, via a package manager like brew.

Comment: Agree with @algal. I have `/usr/local/bin/gls` installed via `brew install coreutils`, and that supports the `--time-style` option.  The OP may have run `brew install coreutils --with-default-names` which would result in `/usr/local/bin/ls` being installed (amongst other utilities), or maybe the OP  set up a manual symlink to `gls`.

Comment: What do you see when you enter `which ls`?